# How do I get the Size Rune?

Tags: mages-of-mystralia

I am trying to get the Size Rune [as described in this thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/529660/discussions/0/1290691308583542982/):

> 4. Size: The Highlands, south of the Ether puzzle. Puzzle requires lighting three torches simultaneously. Right-Duplicate will do the trick if you stand at the right angle.

I am using a controller to control Zia. I can't position her in such a way that my spell hits all three torches at the same time, it seems like I can't control her angle very well.

My Actus spell includes these runes: Move + Right + Duplicate. I've tried with and without adding the Homing Rune.

Is there something else that my spell needs, or is it just a matter of positioning her exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [left][right] and [at once] runes, create three spells: one goes straight, one to left and last to right, in conjunction with [at once] runes. This should be able to hit all three torches.

**Stand Here:**

[image]